# How to check Excel cell format in C# to see if cell value is a date

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

Good Morning All!

I have been developing a project for some time in which users can publish a set of values for a set of dates.

e.g. The user would select a Range in Excel which would contain date values, and an equally sized Range which contains values to publish corresponding to these dates.

What I need to do (C#) is check the cell formatting of both Ranges to see which one is 'actually' a date, I've been using ExcelDNA and since all dates are returned as doubles, I can technically parse my 'values' to dates, and cause all kinds of problems.

If I can get the cell formatting, I can see whether the cell is actually meant to be a date!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Range.NumberFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.numberformat.aspx) should help you determine if a given cell/range is formatted to a date.  If the cell/range is date formatted then the NumberFormat property will contain the format string, i.e. dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Cheers Tony, I'll give this a go, currently have a 'range' location stored in a string so will do a bit of processing and see if this works out!