# Handling excel times imported from excel using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledb, ms-jet-ace

I am importing an excel file using `C# and JetOLEDb (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB for excel 2010 and beyond)`, and I am using the following code:

```
  var fileName = @"C:\myexcel.xlsx";
        var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;", fileName);

        var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", connectionString);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds, "anyNameHere");
        System.Data.DataTable data = ds.Tables["anyNameHere"];
```

The problem is

> when I am trying to import DateTime values, these values are returned
>   as excel times, for example "03/01/2013" is returned as 41334.

How to transform these values to .net DateTime, and how check if they are date time values or just normal doubles

Comment: You can start with `DateTime.FromOADate(date)` to do the conversion to DateTime from double. [DotNetPearls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/fromoadate)

Comment: Thanks, but how to check if these values were originally Date Time values, or just normal doubles

Comment: You should be able to use Interop, and build your data in a loop.  You could check `Range.NumberFormat` on each cell to see if it was a date or double ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964230/how-to-check-excel-cell-format-in-c-sharp-to-see-if-cell-value-is-a-date)).  I think in your current approach you would not have access to that information.